# Add property to object with key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I have a simple code like this:

```
var name = 'line1';
var obj = {};
obj.name = [0, 1];
console.log(obj);
```

Key of property is `name`. But I want to make `key='line'`. Can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and you want to use the value of the `name` variable as the property name, you can use this syntax:

```
obj[name] = [0, 1]; //obj.line1 will be [0, 1]
```

Object properties can also be accessed with the same syntax arrays use. It is handy in situations like this one.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
obj[name]
```

or

```
obj["line1"]
```

This is known as the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), and can be used to access any property of an object.